# Too many series drawn with unused CSV data column

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I have CSV data from an external data source, of which I do not want to display all columns. Nevertheless all columns are mapped to series.
Can I display only certain columns as series without changing the CSV data?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martindfurrer/qt7hwko5/

CSV data:

```
"Year";"total (unused)";"Sector 1";"Sector 2";"Sector 3"
"2011";4380;522;1154;2704
"2012";4768;497;1172;3099
"2013";4824;488;1162;3174
"2014";4891;486;1162;3243
"2015";4948;479;1177;3292
"2016";4901;476;1112;3313
"2017";4858;448;1074;3336
"2018";4856;453;1068;3335
```

Javascript:

```
data: {
   csv: document.getElementById('csvdata').innerHTML,
   itemDelimiter: ';',
   firstRowAsNames: false,
   startRow: 1,
   seriesMapping: [{
         x: 0,
         y: 2,
      },{
         x: 0,
         y: 3,
      },{
         x: 0,
         y: 4,
   }],
},
series: [{
      name: 'Sector 1',
   },{
      name: 'Sector 2',
   },{
      name: 'Sector 3',
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add empty objects to `seriesMapping`:

```
    data: {
        ...,
        seriesMapping: [
            {
                x: 0,
                y: 2,
            }, 
            ..., 
            {}
        ],
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rewfq8v7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

---

Or modify the data, for example in the `parsed` function:

```
    data: {
        ...,
        parsed: function(data) {
            data.splice(1, 2);
        },
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jtL6e1xz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed